# Bash - Changing configuration file with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, configuration

I've been having some problems with a shell script that changes a configuration file named ".backup.conf".

The configuration file looks like this:

```
inputdirs=(/etc /etc/apm /usr/local)
outputdir="test_outputdir"
backupmethod="test_outputmethod"
loglocation="test_loglocation"`
```

My script needs to change one of the configuration file variables, and I've had no trouble with the last 3 variables.

If I wanted to change variable "inputdirs" /etc/ to /etc/perl, what expression should I use?

If I use echo with append, it will only append it to the end of the file.

I've tried using sed in the following format:
`sed -i 's/${inputdirs[$((izbor-1))]}/$novi/g' .backup.conf` where "izbor" is which variable I want to change from  inputdirs and "novi" is the new path (e.g. /etc/perl).

So, with the following configuration file, and with variables `$izbor=1`and `$novi=/etc/perl` I should change the first variable `inputdirs=/etc` to `/etc/perl`
and the variable inputdirs should finally look like `inputdirs=(/etc/perl /etc/apm /usr/local)`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sed is a stream editor.  You're doing a RegEx search/replace on a string...but trying to operatate on arrays?

Comment: Shouldn't sed be searching the whole file for the criteria if used with /g?

Comment: That's not what `g` does, `g` is "replace all".  But regardless - your search expression is invalid.  http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1

Comment: Would you mind correcting it or suggest something with variables? I'm all out of ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
enovi="$(printf '%s\n' "$novi" | sed -e 's/[\\&/]/\\&/g')"
izbor1="$(expr "$izbor" - 1)"
sed -rie "s/([(]([^ ]* ){$izbor1})[^ )]*/\\1$enovi/" config.txt
```

A summary of the commands:

1. The first line generates a variable `$enovi` that has the escaped contents of `$novi`. Basically,the following characters are escaped: `&`, `\`, and `/`. So `/etc/perl` becomes `\/etc\/perl`.
2. We create a new variable decrementing `$izbor`.
3. This is the actual substitute expression. I'll explain it in parts:

   1. First we match the parenthesis character `[(]`.
   2. We will now search for a sequence of non-spaces followed by a space (`[^ ]*`).
   3. This search (identified by grouping in the inner parenthesis) is repeated `$izbor1` times (`{$izbor1}`)
   4. The previous expressions are grouped into an outer parenthesis group in order to be captured into an auxiliary variable `\1`.
   5. We now match the word we want to replace. It is formed by a sequence of characters that aren't spaces and isn't a closing parenthesis (this is to handle the case of the last word)
   6. The replacement is formed by the captured value `\1`, followed by our new string.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I'm getting sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that `$novi` is a path, so it confuses sed. The fix is to escape the string before using it, so I updated the post to create a new variable `$enovi` that contains an escaped version of `$novi`.

Comment: This one seemed to work, but the variable in conf file looks like this now: `inputdirs=( /etc/apm /usr/local)` but should look like `inputdirs=(*value that i entered* /etc/apm /usr/local)`

Comment: Hopefully this fixes everything =). The wrong error was caused by three problems: it wouldn't match the last parameter because it didn't consider that the word could end with a `)`; there has to be a larger parenthesis group around `[(]([^ ]* ){$izbor1}` in order to capture all previous matches; izbor must be decremented before it can be used.

Comment: Well, I hate to bring it down, but the inputdirs still has only ( /etc/apm /usr/local) :(

Comment: It's working like a charm! I can't thank you enough for this!

Comment: No problem! It was a little more difficult than I expected, but I'm happy to have helped a little =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use $izbor as an index, it will probably want to be a flag to `s///`.  Assuming your input matches `^inputdirs=(` (with no whitespace), you can probably get away with:

```
sed -i '/^inputdirs=(/{ 
    s/(/(  /; s/)/ )/;   # Insert spaces inside parentheses
    s@ [^ ][^ ]* @ '"$novi@$izbor"'; 
    s/( /(/; s/ )/)/; }  # Remove inserted spaces
' .backup.conf
```

The first two expressions ensure that you have whitespace inside the parentheses,
so may not be necessary if your input already has whitespace there.  It's a bit obfuscated above, but basically the replacement you are doing is something like:

```
s@ [^ ][^ ]* @/etc/perl@2
```

where the `2` flag tells sed to only replace the second occurrence of the match.  This is really fragile, since it requires no whitespace before `inputdirs` and whitespace inside the parens and does not handle tabs, but it should work for you.  Also, some `sed` allow `[^ ][^ ]*` to be written more simply as `[^ ]+`, but that is not universal.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, however I'm getting `unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`

Comment: My mistake--edited.  There was a single quote missing after `izbor"`.

Comment: Tested it and it worked, but it added a space in front so now it looks like `inputdirs=(  /etc/perl/etc/apm /usr/local )`

Comment: Yes, the space was explicitly added to make the match.  You can remove it with `-e 's/( /(/'`.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: It's working! It seems I have 2 right answers. Thank you very much William!